# How do i update jenkins job configuration and trigger build programatically using java?

Tags: jenkins

I am developing a web application which will take input from user and on clicking on submit button, it will execute the test cases in the backend and show the result on the UI. I am building that application on top of jenkins. How do i update jenkins job configuration  programatically using java ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Jenkin's [Remote Access API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)? With this you can,

> 1. retrieve information from Jenkins for programmatic consumption.
> 2. trigger a new build
> 3. create/copy jobs

according to the documentation. 
You can call this API from an HTTP client written in java. However, if your requirement is to edit an existing job, I'm not sure this would help as it says it allows "create/copy a job"

Comment: yes. I have used config.xml to update job configuration, I am able to see the changes in the configuration but I am not able to save the configuration